# Парсинг ссылок в одинаковых классах

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, selenium

Нужно получить все ссылки, находящиеся в атрибуте `href` тега `а` элемента списка `li` класса `category_list_cell.col-xs-12.col-sm-6.col-md-3`. Основная проблема для меня в том, что этот класс одинаков у всех элементов списка. Как бы мне так правильно подобраться, чтобы получить все ссылки?

```
 browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\user\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject1\\chromedriver.exe")
eq = ['Датчики DUNGS',
      'Регуляторы DUNGS',
      'Клапаны DUNGS',
      'Мультиблоки DUNGS',
      'Блоки контроля герметичности DUNGS',
      'DUNGS VPS 504',
      'DUNGS VDK',
      'DUNGS VPM-VC',
      'Принадлежности',
      'Фильтры DUNGS',
      'Приводы DUNGS',
      'Заслонки DUNGS',
      'Краны DUNGS',
      'Автоматика DUNGS',
      'Запчасти DUNGS',
      'Системная инженерия DUNGS']


def transliterate(name):
    slovar = {'а': 'a', 'б': 'b', 'в': 'v', 'г': 'g', 'д': 'd', 'е': 'e', 'ё': 'yo',
              'ж': 'zh', 'з': 'z', 'и': 'i', 'й': 'i', 'к': 'k', 'л': 'l', 'м': 'm', 'н': 'n',
              'о': 'o', 'п': 'p', 'р': 'r', 'с': 's', 'т': 't', 'у': 'yu', 'ф': 'f', 'х': 'h',
              'ц': 'c', 'ч': 'ch', 'ш': 'sh', 'щ': 'sht', 'ъ': '', 'ы': 'y', 'ь': '', 'э': 'e',
              'ю': 'u', 'я': 'ya', 'А': 'a', 'Б': 'b', 'В': 'v', 'Г': 'g', 'Д': 'd', 'Е': 'e', 'Ё': 'yo',
              'Ж': 'zh', 'З': 'z', 'И': 'i', 'Й': 'yo', 'К': 'k', 'Л': 'l', 'М': 'm', 'Н': 'n',
              'О': 'o', 'П': 'p', 'Р': 'r', 'С': 's', 'Т': 't', 'У': 'u', 'Ф': 'f', 'Х': 'h',
              'Ц': 'c', 'Ч': 'ch', 'Ш': 'sh', 'Щ': 'sht', 'Ъ': '', 'Ы': 'y', 'Ь': '', 'Э': 'E',
              'Ю': 'yu', 'Я': 'ya', 'A': 'а', 'B': 'b', 'V': 'v', 'G': 'g', 'D': 'd', 'E': 'e', 'Z': 'z', 'I': 'i',
              'O': 'o', 'P': 'p', 'R': 'r', 'S': 's', 'T': 't', 'U': 'u', 'F': 'f', 'H': 'h', '" ': '-',
              'C': 'c', 'K': 'k', 'L': 'l', 'M': 'm', ',': '-', '?': '', ' ': '-', 'ґ': '', 'ї': '', 'є': '',
              'Ґ': 'g', 'Ї': 'i', 'Є': 'e', 'N': 'n', ' - ': '-', '/': '-', '\\': '-', 'Ø': '', '"': ''}
    for key in slovar:
        name = name.replace(key, slovar[key])
    name = re.sub('-{2,}', '-', name)
    return name


def output():
    o = 0
    for q in eq:
        browser.get('https://dungs.rusmark.ru/' + transliterate(q))
        requiredHtml = browser.page_source
        listik = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("category_list_cell.col-xs-12.col-sm-6.col-md-3")
        for l in listik:
            print(l.text)
            link = l.find_element_by_tag_name("a").get_attribute("href")
            browser.get(link)
            listik1 = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("button_detail")
            for k in listik1:
                k = k.get_attribute("href")
                print(k)
            browser.get('https://dungs.rusmark.ru/' + transliterate(q))
            o += 1
if __name__ == '__main__':
    output()
```

HTML:

```
<li class="category_list_cell col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
  <div class="category_list_item">
   <div class="category_list_item_wrap">
    <div class="category_list_item_image">
      <a href="/datchiki-dungs/dungs-gw-a5.html">
      </a>
    </div>
    <a class="product_link" href="/datchiki-dungs/dungs-gw-a5.html" title="DUNGS GW A5">
     DUNGS GW A5</a>
   </div>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="category_list_cell col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
 <div class="category_list_item">
  <div class="category_list_item_wrap">
   <div class="category_list_item_image">
    <a href="/datchiki-dungs/dungs-gw-a6.html">
    </a>
   </div>
   <a class="product_link" href="/datchiki-dungs/dungs-gw-a6.html" title="DUNGS GW A6">
   DUNGS GW A</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</li>
```

При запуске данного Python кода первый цикл работает нормально, а далее выползает следующая ошибка:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.121)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было сохранять состояние страницы, посему заменил строчки

```
listik = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("category_list_cell.col-xs-12.col-sm-6.col-md-3")
        for l in listik:
            link = l.find_element_by_tag_name("a").get_attribute("href")
```

на следующие:

```
listik = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("category_list_cell.col-xs-12.col-sm-6.col-md-3")
        listik = len(listik)
        for l in range(listik):
            link = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("category_list_cell.col-xs-12.col-sm-6.col-md-3")[o].find_element_by_tag_name("a").get_attribute("href")
```